# How to prove that if T is a formally complete set of sentences, then T ⊢ (R→S)if and only if either T ̸⊢ R or T ⊢ S(or both)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question goes as follows:

Prove that if T is a formally complete set of sentences, then
T ⊢ (R→S)if and only if either T ̸⊢ R or T ⊢ S(or both).

does T ̸⊢ R or T ⊢ S need to be assumed in order to construct the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does T ̸⊢ R or T ⊢ S need to be assumed in order to construct the proof?

Yes.   You are asked to prove an equivalence (if-and-only-if), so you need a biconditional proof (ie a two directional implication).   So...

1. Show that all interpretations where $\mathrm T\vdash R\to S$, will entail at least one of $\mathrm T\nvdash R$ or $\mathrm T\vdash S$.
2. Show that interpretations where either of $\mathrm T\nvdash R$ or $\mathrm T\vdash S$, will entail $\mathrm T\vdash R\to S$.   (IE: Use a proof by cases approach.)

Comment: Well, I suppose you might use a proof by contraposition instead ... but ... why?